# New line character is not preserved when I retrieve from xml file. I have used cdata

Tags: c#, xml, mstest

I am new to unit test case writing using mstest framework and I am stuck in retrieving new line character from the xml file as an input to expected value. Below is the piece of test method

```
public void ExtractNewLineTest()

{
    MathLibraray target = new MathLibraray(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    string expected = TestContext.DataRow["ExpectedValue"].ToString(); => I am retrieving the value from the xml file.
    string actual;
    actual = target.ExtractNewLine();
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Below is the xml content

```
<ExtractNewLineTest>
      <ExpectedValue><![CDATA[select distinct\tCDBREGNO,\r\n\tMOLWEIGHT,\r\n\tMDLNUMBER\r\nfrom Mol]]></ExpectedValue>
 </ExtractNewLineTest>
```

When I retrieve the data from the xml to expected value, I am getting below string

```
ExpectedValue = “select distinct\\tCDBREGNO,\\r\\n\\tMOLWEIGHT,\\r\\n\\tMDLNUMBER\\r\\nfrom Mol”;
```

If we see the above value, extra slash is getting added for both \n and \r.
Please let me know, how I can assert this value. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your XML file doesn't contain a newline. It contains a backslash followed by a `t`, `r` or `n`. That combination is faithfully being read from the XML file, and then the debugger is escaping the backslash when it's displaying it to you.

If you want to apply "C# string escaping" rules to the value you read from the XML, you can do so, but you should be aware that you do *need* to do so. A simplistic approach would be:

```
expectedValue = expectedValue.Replace("\\t", "\t")
                             .Replace("\\n", "\n")
                             .Replace("\\r", "\r")
                             .Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

There are cases where that will do the wrong thing - for example if you've got a *genuine* backslash followed by a `t`. It may be good enough for you though. If not, you'll have to write a "proper" replacement which reads the string from the start and handles the various cases.

Comment: Can you please help me how to assert in this scenario. That will be great!

Comment: @vasujc: Once you've got the *right* expected value, you can just assert as normal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs!!! It did help me to fix my issue. I will also keep track